# how could get children nodes by getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, getelementbyid

I am trying to access to children of body by getElementById using following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var body = document.getElementById("textBody");
  var x = body.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
  for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("h1");
    var z = x[i].getElementsByTagName("mynode");
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      y[i].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
      z[i].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.democlass {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
  <body id="textBody">
      <div class="myDIV">
        <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
        <mynode> hi there </mynode>
      </div>
    
      <div class="myDIV">
        <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
        <mynode> hi there </mynode>  
      </div>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
    
      <p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>
    
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
```

The code should color the header text into red color. But it seems not to be working for me. Would you please let me know why? What I know it could not have access to the exact nodes which I am waiting for.

Comment: getElementById is only document's method.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID `myDIV`. IDs are meant to be unique. You should use a class name instead.

Comment: @gurvinder372 @ Titus , sorry it was getElementsByClassName(). it was my mistake to edit my code

Answer (score 0):

In your styling you are referring to the `democlass` as a class whereas it is set as an `id` attribute. You can refer to my code for changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
 <body class="textBody">
      <div class="myDIV">
        <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
        <mynode> hi there </mynode>
      </div>

      <div class="myDIV">
        <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>
        <mynode> hi there </mynode>  
      </div>
      <h1 name="demoNode">Hello World</h1>

      <p>Click the button to create a "class" attribute with the value "democlass" and insert it to the H1 element above.</p>

      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
<script>    
function myFunction() {
      //var body = document.getElementsByClassName("textBody"); (This code is not required)
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
      for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {  
        var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("h1");
        var z = x[i].getElementsByTagName("mynode");
//initialise the second loop with a different variable

        for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            y[j].setAttribute("id", "democlass");
            z[j].setAttribute("id", "democlass");
        }
      }
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
//Id reference for styling  
 #democlass {
      color: red;
    }
    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the edited version. It was a typo mistake. sorry!

Comment: typo mistake in which line?

Comment: Please check the code above. It was in JS, CSS code.